# Add Age/sex as covariates when the groups are already Age- and Sex-matched?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-model, matching

**Context:* I am working on a *longitudinal study* that aim to analyse a response variable in Alzheimer's disease population and determine the differences between 4 groups of the AD population*

- I want to fit a linear mixed model and I was wondering if **it's necessary to add the *age* and *sex* as *covariates* in my model when the groups are already *age- and sex-matched*?** :

  `LMM.fit<-lmer(DV ~ Groups + Age + Sex + (1|Subject),data)`
- If the answer is yes (I need to add age and sex as covariates in my model), can I just skip the age- and sex-matching step in the future (since there is an adjustment for Age and Sex in the model)?